# php : Unable to authenticate user login

Tags: php, html

This is a snapshot of my db: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHekM.png) [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSez5.png)

db.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","organisation");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

login.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
require('db.php');
session_start();
// If form submitted, insert values into the database.
if (isset($_POST['username'])){
        // removes backslashes
    $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']);
        //escapes special characters in a string
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username);
    $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
    //Checking is user existing in the database or not
        $query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$username'and password='".md5($password)."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($rows==1){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            // Redirect user to index.php
        header("Location: index.php");
         }else{
    echo "<div class='form'>
<h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3>
<br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
    }
    }else{
?>
<div class="form">
<h1>Log In</h1>
<form action="" method="post" name="login">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

My best guess is that $rows returns false hence I am unable to authenticate the user. I have double checked the code, but I can't seem to find any fault in my db connection.

Comment: Hello. Yhou should learn about SQL injection and how to prevent them. Your code is not save, escaping strings won't prevent injections. http://bobby-tables.com - Also, learn about how to handle passwords and how to store them. Learn about encryptions and hashs. DOn't store your password as plaintext. Learn about the `password_verifiy()` function. Your code is not good at all and shouldn't be used in this state for a productive environment.

Comment: Beside the bad practice with vulnerable SQL, MD5 password hashing and the pointless stripslashes on a hashed password... Look at your database.. The password is in clear text but you're hashing it in MD5. Login fails because credentials do not match

Comment: $row == 1 is exactly 1 ? Also check $username and $password variable  values.

Comment: ***You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score -2):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='".$username."'and password='".md5($password)."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($rows>=1){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            // Redirect user to index.php
        header("Location: index.php"); exit();
```

Comment: @IsThisJavascript there is a possibility of duplicate user entered. so database returns greater than 1. so when comapred to number of rows == 1, it will return false. I also change the $username, it should be concatenated properly or wrapped with {}

Comment: This is a more "what if" situation than an actual solution. The OP has only 1 data entry in their database to start with. Secondly a duplicate user should not exist in the first place.. Thirdly I'd say it's much better to let MySQL handle this by adding `LIMIT 1` to the query. Fourth; the OP, if moved to using the correct `password_hashing` procedure, would eventually ditch the need for `num_rows`

Comment: The issue with OP's situation is clearly a data issue as he's running `md5()` on the password but in his database the password is in plain text. I'd upvote your question if it addressed all the errors and issues with OP's code but as it stands, it does not solve OP's error